# Open data in US which can provide with live traffic?

Tags: data-request, geospatial, traffic, real-time

Is there any open source dataset I can use for my project about live traffic data?
So that I can visualize something like shown in this [visual-link](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=5d226b2ade584226a2aed2db848bb7d5#visualize)

I found the data in the same domain at this [data-link](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=f2b9638492ca4b4ea477801ff110956f#data)
I guess this uses [Waze Jam Data](https://data.cityofboston.gov/Transportation/Waze-Jam-Data/yqgx-2ktq), If not I couldn't download the data from [data-link](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=f2b9638492ca4b4ea477801ff110956f#data).

Is There any alternative dataset I can use? preferably live traffic data.

In these datasets I found there is the UUID encoded location. How can I decode or how can I use in my application?

Say I'm using Tableau for this.

Comment: Tableau is not open source, doesn't use an open format, from what I've heard does accessibility really poorly. For a split-second, I debated whether to even answer this, because you are using it and posting here.  
I do and must, again, its not open at all. If you'd like to hear about possible open source/code/format/data solutions to replace Tableau, feel free to reach out here.

Answer (score 1):

Does transit count as traffic?
GTFS transit feeds for most of the US can be found at [Transit feeds](http://transitfeeds.com/)
I'm not sure what UUID is, I'm assuming its the id for each point on that map; the data-link you specified shows the data promptly on screen after pageload.
Its the tabular data, four columns wide, depth running below the fold. UUID is one column header, looks like lat/lon are two more.
That's a geocoded CSV...you should be good to go.